# How to setup a VPN server using Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I wanted to setup a VPN connection to my home network, since there are several web services I'd like access to remotely and several computers at home I'd like to RDP into.

My router at home is a DGL-4500 which has a VPN pass-through feature (which seems to be a fancy way of saying port forwarding for VPN).

I run a domain controller and DNS server at home on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. I'd like this computer to be the funnel point for my VPN connections and thus it should be the VPN server.

Is there a dummy's how-to guide that gives step by step instructions on how to configure my server at home to run as a VPN server? I did some Google searching on this, but this is one of the rare circumstances where I'm not able to find any good information on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes!!! [How to Configure a Windows VPN in less than 5 minutes](http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2010/09/how-to-configure-windows-vpn-in-less.html).

Whilst I know linking to answers like this is frowned upon, I hope it is different as it is my actual blog post and it has pictures that are hard to copy.

I think it covers everything you want, but if there are any follow up questions you have, let me know.

Comment: as that's a pretty long answer... I'll give the +1 for a good blog post :P